# Как скрыть объект после 1 показа на странице

Tags: javascript, html

.Здравствуйте. Нужно сделать так чтобы блок показался на странице лишь один раз при входе на нее. Подскажите как реализовать данную функцию.

Comment: проставь в куку параметр и проверяй.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp - - как варант, при входе на страницу запросить еще несуществующий `localStorage.getItem("bubu")` — и если он равен undefined, показать блок и создать `localStorage.setItem("bubu")` — В следующий раз при входе на страницу (с этого же браузера) - уже не будет показываться.

Comment: Тогда сядьте и расслабьтесь

Comment: @stckvrw слава богу, что у нас еще есть возможность оставаться относительно анонимными в сети.